# Why my program is not taking user's input more than twice?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

The question is: "Write a program that will have the user enter words until the word "quit" is entered. Display the number that represents all the characters typed, with the exception of the last word, "quit".

Here, I am trying to write the code without using for/while loop. My code is:

```
def num():
summ = 0
inp = input ("Enter: ")

if inp != "quit":
    for w in inp:
        summ += 1

    inp = input("Enter: ")
else:
    return (summ)

print(num())
```

I am using Python 3.7. Even I am taking user input on line 9, still it is not accepting user input again and again, until the user writes "quit". May I please know why this is wrong? Can I write this program without using any loop?
Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your program to act like a loop you need to call your function from within your function (recursion)

```py
def num(summ = 0):
    inp = input ("Enter: ")

    if inp != "quit":
        for w in inp:
            summ += 1

        return num(summ) // Call the function again to continue the program
    else:
        return summ // Return the sum

print(num())
```

You also need to pass your `summ` variable in each call.

> Note: `summ = 0` mean that if you do not pass the argument it should default to 0

Hopefully, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The if statement is not a loop, so your inner `for` loop will be executed these many times: `the length of the first input`.
Your best best is a loop. In this case, a `while` seems apt:

```
def num():
    summ = 0
    inp = input ("Enter: ")

    while inp != "quit":
        for w in inp:
            summ += 1
        inp = input("Enter: ")
    else:
        return (summ)

print(num())
```